# How to show VCs for send e mail, sms, tweet and Facebook status post sequentially for iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter, ios7

I'm trying to **send GPSLocation Coordinates of the iPhone to a recipientList via SMS,EMAIL and post it to Facebook and tweet it on Twitter** in a button clicked.(I get the recipientMail and phoneNumber list from other tab view)

But whatever I tried, I could not make the mail,message,twitter,and Facebook sending views presented sequentially.

Please help me, any help will be appreciated.

I am developing with **Xcode 5** and **iOS 7**.

I got these message(I guess present null is because of simulator cannot simulate sending SMS, for other message I have no idea about the reason behind it)

**2014-01-05 14:26:47.232 iPanic[4760:70b] Attempt to present (null) on  which is waiting for a delayed presention of  to complete**

**2014-01-05 14:26:47.236 iPanic[4760:70b] Attempt to present  on  which is waiting for a delayed presention of  to complete**

My Tab Controller FirstViewController: MRHFirstViewController.m is below:

```
#import "MRHFirstViewController.h"

@interface MRHFirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation MRHFirstViewController


@synthesize emergencyContacts;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
emergencyContacts = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                     objectForKey:@"recipients"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
NSString *latitude= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g°", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g°", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSString *SILlatitude= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *SILlongitude=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];    

NSString *message =[NSString
                    stringWithFormat:@"Hi,I need help.MyGPSlocation: %@, %@.Please Help Me Immediately. http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@,%@ "
                    ,latitude,longitude,SILlatitude,SILlongitude];

 //Send Mail START
mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailComposer setToRecipients:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"emailList"]];
[mailComposer setSubject:@"Help!!!"];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
 //Send Mail END



//SEND SMS START
messageComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
[messageComposer setRecipients:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"phoneList"]];
[messageComposer setBody:message];
messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:messageComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
//SEND SMS END

//tweet and FB START
SLComposeViewController *composeController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

[composeController setInitialText:message];
//[composeController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
//[composeController addURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];

[self presentViewController:composeController
                   animated:YES completion:nil];

SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) //check if Facebook Account is linked
    {
        mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init]; //initiate the Social Controller
        mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]; //Tell him with what social plattform to use it, e.g. facebook or twitter
        [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:message]; //the message you want to post
        //[mySLComposerSheet addImage:yourimage]; //an image you could post
        //for more instance methodes, go here:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205
        [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

        NSLog(@"Account is linked!!!");
    }else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"lan" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"Account is not linked hafiz");
    }

};
composeController.completionHandler =myBlock;
    //tweet and FB END

}

- (IBAction)doPanic:(id)sender {

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

MRHFirstViewController.h below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface MRHFirstViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
{
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageComposer;
SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet;
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *emergencyContacts;
@property NSString *SILlat;
@property NSString *SILlon;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *silLabel;
- (IBAction)doPanic:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the twitter and Facebook code parts into the method : (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should present the new view controller in the completion delegate callback. That is, when, for example, your twitter delegate tells you that the tweet have been sent, present the mail view controller, when it's delegate told you it finished, present Facebook view controller, and so on (in the order you want).